# Eclipse file names on tabs are not in english

Tags: eclipse

When using eclipse software, the tabs which should have the filename are like this:

[image]

I don't have any problem in the workspace view. Those seem to show up in english. It's just my tabs at the top that mess up.

I tried reinstalling, changing workspace, deleting metadata, but nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: What do you have in _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_ configured as _Part Title Font_? Does choosing a different font here fix your issue? Do you run Eclipse on Window, on Linux or on macOS? Please note, deleting the `.metadata` folder is a hoax (never ever do this).

Comment: Thanks. It was Segoe UI. I even resetted it but it remained the same. Anyways, I changed it to Inconsolata, and it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This looks rather like a font than a language issue. Since switching to a new workspace without copying the settings did not help, it is obviously that the default font causing this issue.

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** choose a different font for ***View and Editor Folders > Part Title Font*** than the default font.

Alternatively, a reinstallation of this default font might also fix this issue.

Please note, deleting the `.metadata` folder is a hoax. Never ever do this. You will lose non project-specific preferences, unshared launch configurations, the local history, and much more depending on the installed plug-ins. Instead, switch to a new empty workspace without copying the settings as you did.